# Server refuses redirect from https to https

Tags: php, redirect, https

I am trying to redirect a site via `PHP` header

from:

https://example.com/program.php?param1=abc

to:

https://example.com/program.php?param1=abc&param2=123

by:

header("Location: https://example.com/program.php?param1=abc&param2=123");

The server refuses the connection and tells me that the following error appeared ( translated ):

> "The website cannot be shown because authenticity of the received data
>   cannot be verified."

I am confused because I want to redirect to the exact same site just with an added parameter, from `https` to `https`.

At the moment I am using a `JavaScript- Injection` like

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "https://example.com/program.php?param1=abc&param2=123"``
</script>'
```

because a `meta-refresh asks` for user permission to function.

Please be so kind and tell me what I am doing wrong with the `php-header`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you please be so kind and _show us_ what exactly you are doing first of all. [ask], [mre]

Comment: You reference Javascript Injection in your question, but have tagged `PHP`. Which method will you use?

Comment: Are you able to edit the PHP script? If so then might it be better to avoid redirection entirely and have that script handle any missing parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As it's a bit unclear what you are exactly trying to do, I'll try to give you a more generic answer.

You could use this construct to redirect using a 302 temporary redirect

```
header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
header("Location: https://example.com/program.php?param1=abc&param2=123"); 
exit();
```

Comment: Hi Christiaan, I am trying to add a parameter manually if it's missing. Your suggestion leads to the same result. The server tells me the same.

Comment: Hey @Paul, are you sure it is the server who returns this? There are cases where it's the antivirus / anti-malware that intercepts the redirect and triggers the message... (found this here: https://support.mozilla.org/nl/questions/1117296)

Comment: As mentioned on the site you supposed I tried this link in the firefox browser: chrome://pippki/content/exceptionDialog.xul   which opened a window where I should enter the desired website which not loads. I did so and the browsers answer was that the certificate is valid and no exception had to be added.                If I may mention it again, I am staying on the same site only adding a parameter and redirect to the site itself which I can view before redirecting.       Next I turned my personal firewall off but the result stays the same again.